"Recursion must act on a single discriminating argument." Doesn't recursion act on both in this recursive definition of subtraction?
Here is the extract from Gert Smolka's book on computational type theory.
Isn't it the case that within the third pattern, we apply negation to the variables obtained by discriminating both arguments and not the first one exclusively?
Here is my implementation of a function in Coq that returns true if and only if the first natural argument is less than the second. I use a recursive call applied to the variables obtained by discriminating both arguments within the definition, don't I?
Fixpoint less_than (n m : nat) :=
  match n with
  | 0 =>
    match m with
    | 0 => false
    | S y => true
    end
  | S x =>
    match m with
    | 0 => false
    | S y => less_than x y
    end
  end.


In both cases recursion indeed happens on the first argument, this does not mean that the other arguments need to always remain the same. Discriminating some other term doesn't change what recursion is done on.

@ThéoWinterhalter, thank you for your reply. I have a clarifying question. What might the author want to say by "single" in "must act on a single discriminating argument?"

That if there is not one argument that decreases with every recursive call, it's ill-typed. I.e. you can't mix two, using sometimes one and sometimes the other.

@JoJoModding, thank you for your response! Could you provide a brief example of ill-formed recursion in this understanding? It would help me grasp the critical importance of this requirement.

Something like f where f (S n) 0 := f n n and f (S n) (S m) := f (S n) m maybe? Notice that you can make it work by using two nested fixpoints.

Having discussed the issue with a colleague, we concluded that the author might mean that there must be at least one among the arguments of a recursive function that decreases in all the recursive calls.
